# How to disable the locate command, when used by an ordinary user, from printing file paths that belong to other users?

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions

On Debian with mlocate installed, the locate command seems to print file paths matching a given pattern regardless of the owner. This is a bit privacy instruing. How can I prevent mlocate from displaying file paths owned by other users?

Comment: mlocate already does this by default. What version of Debian are you running and what changes were made to its configuration? And did you do something like run it with sudo?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have never altered its configuration. I am on Debian Buster, upgraded from Stretch, upgraded from Jessie.

Comment: You probably need to fix permissions then. It will only show files where the user can read the containing directory.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I see. I never noticed before mlocate follows this permission. Thanks!